# S3Client Unable to load credentials in QuarkusTest, using QuarkusTestResourceLifecycleManager in quarkus 2+

Tags: java, amazon-s3, quarkus, testcontainers, localstack

I have an error "Unable to load credentials" in my integ test when I upgrade quarkus from 1.13.2 to 2.X.X.

LambdaIntegTest.class :

```
@Testcontainers
@QuarkusTest
@QuarkusTestResource(ContainerRessource.class)
class LambdaIntegTest {

    @Test
    void test() throws Exception {
        String s3Event = oneS3event();

        String out = LambdaClient.invokeJson(String.class, s3Event);

        assertThat(out).isEqualTo("Success");
    }
```

ContainerRessource.class :

```
public class ContainerRessource implements QuarkusTestResourceLifecycleManager {
    private static final LocalStackContainer LOCAL_STACK_CONTAINER;

    static {
        DockerImageName localstackImage = DockerImageName.parse("localstack/localstack:0.11.3");
        LOCAL_STACK_CONTAINER = new LocalStackContainer(localstackImage)
            .withServices(S3);
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> start() {
        LOCAL_STACK_CONTAINER.start();
        innitS3();
        return Map.ofEntries(
            entry("aws.region", LOCAL_STACK_CONTAINER.getRegion()),
            entry("s3.url.override", LOCAL_STACK_CONTAINER.getEndpointOverride(S3).toString()),
            entry("aws.accessKeyId", LOCAL_STACK_CONTAINER.getAccessKey()),
            entry("aws.secretAccessKey", LOCAL_STACK_CONTAINER.getSecretKey()));
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        LOCAL_STACK_CONTAINER.stop();
    }
}
```

I have try to put the credential in the application.properties, but I have the same error.
My test work with Quarkus 1.13.2

I have also a native test :

```
@QuarkusIntegrationTest
public class LambdaNativeTest extends LambdaIntegTest {
}
```

And it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround, If we set manually, the credential, in the system property it worked.
The method start() with the modification :

```
 @Override
    public Map<String, String> start() {
        LOCAL_STACK_CONTAINER.start();
        innitS3();
        System.setProperty("aws.accessKeyId", LOCAL_STACK_CONTAINER.getAccessKey());
        System.setProperty("aws.secretAccessKey", LOCAL_STACK_CONTAINER.getSecretKey());
        return Map.ofEntries(
            entry("aws.region", LOCAL_STACK_CONTAINER.getRegion()),
            entry("s3.url.override", LOCAL_STACK_CONTAINER.getEndpointOverride(S3).toString()),
            entry("aws.accessKeyId", LOCAL_STACK_CONTAINER.getAccessKey()),
            entry("aws.secretAccessKey", LOCAL_STACK_CONTAINER.getSecretKey()));
    }
```

The Javadoc of QuarkusTestResourceLifecycleManager.start() say :
'@return A map of system properties that should be set for the running test'

It seems that that doesn't work with @QuarkusTest